# Why is my UIWebView being misplaced when I add constraints?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, xcode7

Before I add constraints, it appears exactly where it needs to be. However, it is in a UIScrollView, so it needs to be able to scroll up and down with the rest of the content.

So I add the necessary constraints, and when I run the app, the webView appears at the top left corner of the screen. And it does not scroll.

What's going on?

Comment: What constraints did you add?

Comment: Top, width, height, and center horizontally.

Comment: Why do you need a web view inside of a scroll view? A web view, by default has a scroll view within it?

Comment: It's an embedded YouTube video. It's part of a user profile.